# How to revalidate after mutation with react-query?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, react-query

I've a basic implementation of data fetching and updating using **react-query** on **next.js** app.
My goal is to update the data after mutation.
Currently the data updates only on tab refresh. But without user interaction it doesn’t change. 
I found out that data update on tab refresh happens because of `refetchOnWindowFocus` default behaviour. 
But how to invalidate after updating the data on server side.
Here is the related snippet of code.

**Note**: I am making use of **react-query** **SSR** feature using Hydration. [Docs](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/react/guides/ssr#using-hydration)

_app.jsx

```
 const [queryClient] = React.useState(() => new QueryClient());

  return (
    <QueryClientProvider client={queryClient}>
      <Hydrate state={pageProps.dehydratedState}>
          <Component {...pageProps} />
      </Hydrate>
    </QueryClientProvider>
```

Home.jsx

```
  const {data} = useQuery({
    queryKey: [queryKeys.key],
    queryFn: fetchData,
    staleTime: 1000 * 10, // this doesn't affect on anything
    //refetchInterval: 2000, this updates every 2 seconds
  });

  return (
    <div>
      <Article articles={data} />
    </div>
  );
   export const getServerSideProps = async () => {
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();
  await queryClient.prefetchQuery([queryKeys.key], fetchData);
  return { props: { dehydratedState: dehydrate(queryClient) } };
};
```

Article.jsx

```
const Article = ({articles}) => {
  const [title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const queryClient = new QueryClient();

  const { mutate } = useMutation({
    mutationFn: async (article) => {
      return await axios.post(url, article);
    },
    onSuccess: (data) => {
      console.log("data", data) // data is displayed, onSuccess is called
      queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: [queryKeys.key] });
    },
  });

  const changeTitleHandleClick = () => {
    mutate({
      id: new Date(),
      title: title
    });
    setTitle("");
  };
  ....
```

Any help will be appreciated

**UPDATE**: `refetchInterval: 2000` updates every 2 seconds but this triggers network request every 2 seconds so I'm not sure this is the best Practice to revaliadate.

**UPDATE**: Console inside the `onSuccess` method is displayed on mutation, this means that something is wrong with the logic, because even if the keys are different, this should have worked: `queryClient.invalidateQueries()` where I am not specifying any key instead triggering all queries.
But even this doesn't update. Why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem was that in component `Article.jsx` I was creating a new QueryClient in each render, so it was getting a new cache, therefore not updating. 
Instead I had to use `useQueryClient` hook, which returns the current instance.
`const queryClient = useQueryClient();`

Answer (score 5):

The way you've implemented the mutation, it should refetch the query after a successful mutation:

```
onSuccess: () => {
  queryClient.invalidateQueries({ queryKey: [queryKeys.key] });
},
```

If that isn't working, either your mutation wasn't successful. Check if the `onSuccess` callback is called.

If the `onSuccess` callback is called, but your query is not refetched, that likely means the `queryKey` isn't matching. For testing purpose, try widening the filters to just:

```
queryClient.invalidateQueries()
```

that should refetch *all* queries. If that works, you know that your `queryKey` filter wasn't matching.

Looking at it more closely, you are invalidating:

```
queryKey: [queryKeys.key]
```

but in your custom hook, you are using:

```
queryKey: [queryKeys.articles]
```

so it does seem that they are different and thus not matching. Also, be sure to use the `@tanstack/react-query-devtools` to get a better overview of what queries and keys are in your cache.

Comment: thanks for the answer and pointing out the mismatch of `query keys`. 
I fixed it on my post. 
I tried to reproduce my problem with a simple codebase and named them differently by mistake.
I do have `react-query-devtools`, but key seems to be the same, at least I don't see a difference. 
I tested also the way you said. So, in `onSuccess` I fetched on queries but didn't help as well. But what I noticed there, that `onSuccess` is called, I consoled and it works actually. 
Maybe I should make use of `setQueryData`?

Comment: I can take a look at a codesandbox if you have one

Comment: thanks for response. 
I found out that problem was that  in child component I was creating a new QueryClient in each render, so it was getting a new cache, therefore not updating. 
Instead I had to use useQueryClient hook, which returns the current instance.